# How to convert HTML `NSString` to PDF file in osx?

Tags: macos, cocoa, pdf-generation

I am new to the PDF creations from OSX.

I want to convert my HTML file to the PDF file,Please help me out which is best way to convert .

I have try to search but getting only IOS supported classes.

https://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/mobile/ios_pdf_library.html

I have found below link for OSX but some method are deprecated and not properly working.

[PDF Creation in Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118933/pdf-creation-in-cocoa)